# Open custom tabs in fragment

Tags: fragment, chrome-custom-tabs

I have implemented custom tabs in my app and I have bottom navigation bar. When I click on any item in the bottom bar the fragment opens. Inside the fragment the custom tabs have to open. Custom tabs have to be open in a view not as a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Tabs is not a View, but an entire Activity that is hosted in the browser process and handled as part of the application tasks stack. So, it can't be part of another Activity's view hierarchy and can only be used as a standalone Activity.

The Android WebView is a an Android View and can be used inside an Activity. But, 
generally, content opened inside the WebView should be designed with the component in mind, as it doesn't support every API available to modern web apps (eg: push notifications).